# I am making snake in pygame and python is giving me an error that one of my objects is actually a string, but its not meant to be

Tags: python, pygame

The error that shows up in python right now is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Start.py", line 66, in <module>
    snake = snake(self) # create an instance
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Start.py", line 17, in __init__
    food.image = pygame.image.load("food.png")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I am very new to python and pygame, so most of the code I've been using is stuff I've taken and adapted from stack overflow

What I was trying to do with the food object was make it so that it was all in one player class because I am confused on how to call methods from other classes and use objects from other classes in one class. If anyone has any alternatives to what I've done please tell me.
import pygame
import os
import time
import math
import random

```
length = 650
width = 400
headx = 0
heady = 0
class snake(object):
    
    def __init__(self, food):        
        self.image = pygame.image.load("head.png")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        food.image = pygame.image.load("food.png")
        food.x = 0
        food.y = 0
    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Handles Keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 25 # distance moved in 1 frame, try changing it to 5
        
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
            self.y += dist # move down
            heady = heady - dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
            self.y -= dist # move up
            heady = heady - dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
            self.x += dist # move right
            headx = headx - dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
            self.x -= dist # move left
            headx = headx - dist
    def fooddrop(food, surface):
        newfoodx = 1
        newfoody = 1
        while newfoodx % 25 != 0 or newfoodx !=0:
            newfoodx = random.randint(0,650)
        while newfoody % 25 != 0 or newfoody !=0:
            newfoody = random.randint(0,400)
        food.x = newfoodx
        food.y = newfoody
        surface.blit(food.image,(food.x,food.y))
    def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw on surface """
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        


       






self = 'null'
food = 'null'
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((length, width))

snake = snake(self) # create an instance
food = snake(food)

running = True
while running:
    # handle every event since the last frame.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # quit the screen
            running = False
    if snake.y > width or snake.y < 0 or snake.x > length or snake.x < 0: #Border Created
        pygame.quit() # quit the screen
        running = False
    time.sleep(0.125)
    snake.handle_keys() # handle the keys
    screen.fill((0,0,0)) # fill the screen with white
    snake.draw(screen) # draw the snake to the screen   
    snake.fooddrop(screen)
    pygame.display.update() # update the screen

    clock.tick(40)
```

Feel free to completely destroy my code because I am new and need to learn.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `python is giving me an error that one of my objects is actually a string, but its not meant to be` - but it is. You pass string `'null'`, therefore in `__init__` `food=='null'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and instances of classes ([objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)).

Create a class `Snake` (or whatever name). Please use a leading capital letter for the name of the class to avoid confusions (see [Style Guide for Python Code - Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)).
The constructor of the class has 1 parameter (beside `self`), the name of the image:

```py
class Snake(object):

    def __init__(self, imagename):        
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imagename)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

Create 2 instances of the class:

```py
snake = Snake("head.png")
food = Snake("food.png")
```